# Flask consitently showing a 404 Error when attempting to call website's URLs

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

I am writing a piece of code but continue to receive a 404 message for my html pages - specifically, "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 404 - can anyone help as to why this might be happening and fixes for it? I have put the code below and I am using python and flask.

```
@bp.route('/')
@bp.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: Where is your html files ? Are they under `templates` directory as suggested ? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: yes I've put them under templates

Comment: you should access it as `/home`, not `/home.html`.

Comment: hey ilias - that doesn't help it - in fact when I tried this approach earlier it actually made it worse - not sure if that's normal behaviour?

Comment: I have resolved it - I had to put home.html in both rather than removing it in both!